# iOS XML Parser - Which one?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

So I need to decide which iOS XML Parser to use for my new app. I will be downloading large documents from a website and parsing them into TableView cells as well as normal views. So it needs to be quick and easy to use.

Also, I would like the ability to parse the document, while downloading. So if I am scrolling in a tableView - I don't want to UI to lock up due to XML Parsing?

I guess I could use GDC to use overcome this?

I looked at TBXML and the libxml2 SAX XML parsers.

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

p.S: I realise this is a duplicate question - However I wanted to see if TBXML was still used or now deprecated like the ASIHTTPRequest network API (Where AFnetworking is used now)

Comment: IMHO this question should not have been marked as a duplicate because the "original" question is from 2010 and is outdated at this point.

Comment: Completely agree with you there. Which is why I asked this question as I felt it needed an updated response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use TBXML as it takes lowest time comparatively to parse a document. To implement this surely you need multi-threading(GCD). You can implement this like lazy-loading concept, adding more rows as scroll reach to last.

Comment: So I could use CGD to get over the UI locking up as I am scrolling a TableView and then TBXML for the actual Parsing of the data?

Comment: Parse your xml using TBXML with GCD threading.

Comment: Appreciate the help - thank you!

Comment: So I eventually found the info I was looking for: This blog post from January 2013 gives a great picture on which XML Parser to use -based on modern hardware (iPhone 5) 

http://jansanchez.com/blog/2013/01/22/state-of-ios-xml-libraries-in-2013/